# Disable radio buttons by default

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to find a way to make radio buttons disabled by default. I have managed to disable them inside my event handler for `CheckedChanged` but that only works when action is taken by the user. How do I disable the control by default?

```
Private Sub rdoCustomer_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
                                       ByVal e As EventArgs) _    
    Handles rdoCustomer.CheckChanged, rdoDepartment.CheckedChanged

    rdoCustomer.Enabled = False
    rdoCustomer.Checked = True
    rdoDepartment.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inactive"? unchecked, or disabled?

Comment: @Rowland I thought the question was clear in what I was asking and was answered based on the same. I also posted the code that was relevant. Where did you not get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set anything "by default", just write it in the `Form Load Event`. Sample:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    rdoCustomer.Enabled = False
    rdoCustomer.Checked = False
    rdoDepartment.Enabled = False
    rdoDepartment.Checked = False
End Sub
```

Or, alternatively, via properties of the given control(s) in "Design View". All this by assuming that the controls weren't created at runtime (in that case, right after being created).